# Splash Screen for Android in React Native

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

I've followed this.
https://android.jlelse.eu/change-splash-screen-in-react-native-android-app-d3f99ac1ebd1#.5k7trorbf
But this is just creating a specific size for all dimensions. What should i do for other dimensions? I've already generated all the dimensions images and have put them in drawable-xxxx folders. But still specific dimension for all dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I've got success by using `<nine-patch>` instead of `<layer-list>` and the images with `.9`. We've to generate splash from online generators which generate images to be compatible to nine patch. This will stretch the image according to dimensions.